# Hide one of parameters in url

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an url looked like this:

```
example.com/page.php?id=1&type=yes
```

And I have used the following rules in `.htaccess` to hide those parameters

```
#RewriteRule .* https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) /page.php?id=$1
```

and i got this:

```
example.com/page.php/1/yes
```

How can I have an url looks like:

```
**example.com/page.php/yes**
```

my php codes are:

```
echo '<li class="link actived"><a href="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . $row['ID'] . '/' . $secure->toAscii($row['TYPE']) . '">' . $row['TYPE'] . '</a></li>';
```

Best!!

Comment: Why would you want a url like this: `example.com/page.php/type=yes` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, Pedro Lobito!!! I just wanted a url like example.com/page.php/yes not example.com/page.php/type=yes to help people in search when they want to type that url. Thank you

Comment: You will loose your ID if you have a URL like that. how about `example.com/page/1/yes`?

Comment: Twisty, it will better if there is a way i can get example.com/page/yes without losing my ID. Thank you!!